# In MALLET Java API, why can't the Input2CharSequence pipe feed into the CharSequenceLowercase() pipe?

Tags: java, mallet, charsequence

When I try to use these pipes successively, I get the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CharSequenceLowercase expects a String, found a class java.lang.StringBuffer

I don't see any pipes available in MALLET to fix this. But it seems to me CharSequenceLowercase() should be able to take in a CharSequence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment that line and then call

```
pipeList.add(new TokenSequenceLowercase());
```

which lower cases the tokens. It looks like the CharSequenceLowerCase pipe cannot accept a StringBuffer. if you look into its code it accepts only String.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing the following:

`pipeList.add(new Input2CharSequence("UTF-8"));
pipeList.add(new CharSequence2TokenSequence(Pattern.compile("\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")));
pipeList.add( new TokenSequenceLowercase() );`
because CharSequence2TokenSequence didn't seem to have the same problem as CharSequenceLowercase. It still seems to me that both of those pipes should accept the same input, based on the naming conventions, but I guess that's not the case.